# Why can't I create new project using "ng new" syntax

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

**Node Version** v7.0.0

**npm version** v3.10.8

I install "npm install -g angular-cli" on C:\

and create new project on C:\newfolder but unfortunately I got this error:

```
C:\ang>ng new app
module.js:474
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Cindy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:472:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:420:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:382:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:137:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:497:3
```

Answer (score 1):

I Also Tried Doing THis, turned out that updating node to `v7.0.0` was the cause.

From my understanding,

Node 7 has some issues with bindings. It wasnt able to locate bindings in my system.

Uninstalling it & installing node 6.* helped.

Follow these steps:

uninstall node v7.

delete `npm` &  `npm cache` directories in `AppData/Roaming/`.

install node version 6.9.

run `npm cache clean`

& then install angular-cli globally.

If You want , you can track the issue at:

[Github Link For this particular Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3102).

Hope this helps

Comment: I follow the steps you've given but unfortunately I'm not able to install angular-cli. .

Comment: what will be the right path to install "npm install -g angular-cli"?

Comment: On Windows , it is C:\\users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm.You can install it anywhere.just specify -g as` npm install -g angular-cli` this will install it globally.